# jQuery Mobile: workaround for on('change'...)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, dom-manipulation

i am developing a phonegap app atm and have two sets of radio buttons + a dropdown menu, which are supposed to deliver values to load an image later on

desktop wise i work with

```
$('.radioButtonClass').on("click", function () {
    var one = $("input:radio:checked[name=foo]").val();
    var two = $("input:radio:checked[name=bar]").val();
    var three = $("#myList").val();
    $('#myTarget').text(one + '_' + two + '_' + three + 'mm.png');
```

and

```
$('#dropDown').on("change", function () {
    var one = $("input:radio:checked[name=foo]").val();
    var two = $("input:radio:checked[name=bar]").val();
    var three = $("#myList").val();
    $('#myTarget').text(one + '_' + two + '_' + three + 'mm.png');
```

while i also have a switch statement following the change of the dropdown menu later on somehow it seems that i cant even get the values to just be printed to `#myTarget`

i already tried to change the code to `.on('vclick'..)` - which also does not work in jsfiddle - interestingly it does on a helper-overlay which i just `.toggle` and `.on('tap'..)` does neither work in jsfiddle nor on my android-phone(4.2)

pretty sure it is a jQM issue, any hints?

€dit:
here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/X29gJ/

it seems that vclick obviously behaves like .click? and only works one time on the first item it is attached to?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this

Comment: which version of jquery you are using ?

Comment: I am using last-stable jqm1.3.2. - fiddle coming

Comment: for checkboxes, radio buttons, and select use `change`.

Comment: Sorry.. I am trying to understand whats the issue. Can you plz explain more.

Comment: the problem is that desktop variants of click do not work in jQM and on my phone neither "vclick" nor "tap" work - "most of the time", interestingly it does on some items

and in addition the event handler .on('change'...) does not work, so it leaves my application basically without any function at all ^^